# SIGSEGV on free()

Tags: android, memory-management, java-native-interface, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am porting a C program.

The problem I've met is SIGSEGV on free(). I can't see what's the root cause of it. it seems like heap-memory has corrupted by something.
it doesn't occur sometimes, but very often.

malloc didn't return NULL. so memories maybe allocated correctly.

I am testing it on NexusOne 2.2.1
I am using Android NDK r5b and Android SDK and Eclipse ADT and Cygwin.
I am using android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor to read assets in C modules.

Here is the messages in ndk-gdb when the problem appears.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, Java_kr_co_pkbio_Unse_DangSaJuShinSal (env=0xaa50,
    obj=0x4495b970)
    at C:/DEWR/Product/Software-Engineering/Eclipse-Workspace/Unse/jni/unse.c:1
83
1083                    free(strBuf);
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xafd11c80 in __libc_android_abort ()
   from C:/DEWR/Product/Software-Engineering/Eclipse-Workspace/Unse/obj/local/a
meabi/libc.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0xafd11c80 in __libc_android_abort ()
   from C:/DEWR/Product/Software-Engineering/Eclipse-Workspace/Unse/obj/local/a
meabi/libc.so
#1  0xbec233bc in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0xc
(gdb) quit
```

Here is the Java source code...

```
public static HashMap<String, FileInfoForNativeCode> fifnMap = new HashMap<String, FileInfoForNativeCode>();
public static FileInfoForNativeCode openAssets(String fname) {
    FileInfoForNativeCode fifn;

    if (Constants.VERBOSE_LOGS)
        Log.d("TAGG", "TAGG openAssets("+fname+")");

    fifn = fifnMap.get(fname);
    if (fifn != null)
        return fifn;

    AssetFileDescriptor myDescriptor = null;
    try {
        myDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(fname+".jet");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    FileDescriptor fd = myDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    long off = myDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long len = myDescriptor.getLength();

    if (Constants.VERBOSE_LOGS)
        Log.d("TAGG", "TAGG fd:"+fd+" off:"+off+" len:"+len);

    fifn = new FileInfoForNativeCode(off, len, fd, myDescriptor);
    fifnMap.put(fname, fifn);
    return fifn;
}
```

Here is the C source code...

```
char* getTextByIndex (TextFileBufType *filebuf, char *index) {
    #define _INDEX_PREFIX_    '@'
    int        i, j, lenBuf;
    char    *result;
    char    indexPrefix = _INDEX_PREFIX_;
    int        lenIndexPrefix = utf8len( &indexPrefix );
    int        lenIndex = strlen(index);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < filebuf->total ; i++ ) {
        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"TAG", "JNI : %d -> %s", i, filebuf->text[i]);

        if ( memcmp (filebuf->text[i], &indexPrefix, lenIndexPrefix) != 0 )
            continue;

        if ( memcmp (filebuf->text[i]+lenIndexPrefix, index, lenIndex) != 0 )
            continue;

        lenBuf = 0;
        lenBuf += strlen(filebuf->text[i]);
        lenBuf++;
        for ( j = i+1 ; j < filebuf->total ; j++ ) {
            if ( memcmp (filebuf->text[j], &indexPrefix, lenIndexPrefix) == 0 )
                break;

            lenBuf += strlen(filebuf->text[j]);
            lenBuf++;
        }

        result = malloc(lenBuf);
        result[0] = 0;
        strcat(result, filebuf->text[i]);
        strcat(result, "\n");
        for ( j = i+1 ; j < filebuf->total ; j++ ) {
            if ( memcmp (filebuf->text[j], &indexPrefix, lenIndexPrefix) == 0 )
                break;

            strcat(result, filebuf->text[j]);
            strcat(result, "\n");
        }

        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"TAG", "JNI : %d!!! -> %s", i, filebuf->text[i]);
        return result;
    }

    return NULL;

    #undef _INDEX_PREFIX_
}

inline void readyFileInFile (FileInFile *fif, char *path)
{
    jstring jstrFpath;
    jobject finfo;
    jobject descriptor;

    jstrFpath = (*gEnv)->NewStringUTF(gEnv, path);
    finfo = (*gEnv)->CallStaticObjectMethod(gEnv, clsUtility, midOpenAssets, jstrFpath);
    fif->offset = (*gEnv)->GetLongField(gEnv, finfo, fidOffset);
    fif->length = (*gEnv)->GetLongField(gEnv, finfo, fidLength);
    descriptor = (*gEnv)->GetObjectField(gEnv, finfo, fidDescriptor);
    fif->fd = (*gEnv)->GetIntField(gEnv, descriptor, fidDescriptorFileDescriptor);
}

jobjectArray Java_kr_co_pkbio_Unse_DangSaJuShinSal (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
//    char   *fname = "DangSaJu_ShinSal";
    int     i, fileno[4], ret_code, type;
    char    temp[256];
    char   *header[4] = { "년", "월", "일", "시" };
    char    table1[12] = { 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2 };
    char    table2[4]  = {10, 7, 4, 1};

    char   *index[12] = {
        "겁살",   "재살",   "천살",   "지살",   "연살",   "월살",
        "망신살", "장성살", "반안살", "역마살", "육해살", "화개살"
    };

    int        r_option;
    int        numBytesRead;
    char    *strBuf;
    TextFileBufType    filebuf;
    jstring buf_output[4];
    jobjectArray output;
    FileInFile fif;

    gEnv = env;

    /* 년월일시에 대한 겁살을 계산한다 */
    type = table1[BaseInfo.saju.day % 12];
    fileno[0] = (table2[type] + (BaseInfo.saju.year  % 12)) % 12;
    fileno[1] = (table2[type] + (BaseInfo.saju.month % 12)) % 12;
    fileno[2] = (table2[type] + (BaseInfo.saju.day   % 12)) % 12;
    fileno[3] = (table2[type] + (BaseInfo.saju.hour  % 12)) % 12;
    /*WriteMsg (" - 기본위치 : 생일지지(%s) --> type:%d --> 자(%s)에 대한 살:%s\n",
        JeeJeeStr[BaseInfo.saju.day % 12], type, JeeJeeStr[0], index[table2[type]]);
    WriteMsg (" - 년살     : 생년지지(%s) --> 년%s\n", JeeJeeStr[BaseInfo.saju.year % 12],
        index[fileno[0]]);
    WriteMsg (" - 월살     : 생월지지(%s) --> 월%s\n", JeeJeeStr[BaseInfo.saju.month % 12],
        index[fileno[1]]);
    WriteMsg (" - 일살     : 생일지지(%s) --> 일%s\n", JeeJeeStr[BaseInfo.saju.day % 12],
        index[fileno[2]]);
    WriteMsg (" - 시살     : 생시지지(%s) --> 시%s\n", JeeJeeStr[BaseInfo.saju.hour % 12],
        index[fileno[3]]);*/


    readyFileInFile(&fif, "data/DangSaJu5.dat");

    r_option = ((int)'#' << 8) & 0xFF00;   /* Comment char setting */
    r_option |= (RT_OPT_RMCMT | RT_OPT_RMCRLF | RT_OPT_LTRIM | RT_OPT_RTRIM | RT_OPT_SPACES);

    if ( ReadTextFileToBufA (&filebuf, &fif, r_option) < 0 ) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"TAG", "JNI : 서버측에서 치명적인 오류가 발생하여 더이상 진행할 수 없습니다.");
        return NULL;
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        sprintf (temp, "%s%s", header[i], index[fileno[i]]);
        strBuf = getTextByIndex(&filebuf, temp);
        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"TAG", "JNI : %s -> %s", temp, strBuf );
        buf_output[i] = (*gEnv)->NewStringUTF(gEnv, strBuf);
        free(strBuf); //line number : 1083 ***It doesn't cause SIGSEGV on first for-loop-round, but on third for-round.***
        //PrintTextFile3 ("../data/DangSaJu5.dat", temp, VIEW_T_R_STR,
        //    "12신살로 알아보는 인생의 길흉화복 : %s", temp);
        /*if (i < 3) {
            sprintf (temp, "\n 계속해서 %s%s에 대한 풀이를 보시겠습니까? (Y/n)",
                header[i+1], index[fileno[i+1]]);
            ret_code = GetYesNo (temp, GETYN_YES);
            if (ret_code == GETYN_NO)  return;
        }*/
    }

    FreeTextFileBuf (&filebuf);
    //printf ("\n [Enter]키를 누르세요.");  fflush(stdout);
    //PauseUntil (300, 0);
    #if defined (_DO_NOT_COMPILE_)
    {
        int j;
        for (i=0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
            for (j=0 ; j<12 ; j++) {
                sprintf (temp, "%s%s", header[i], index[j]);
                //PrintTextFile3 ("../data/DangSaJu5.dat", temp, VIEW_T_R_STR,
                //    "당사주 / 인생 길흉화복 datafile test : %s", temp);
            }
        }
    }
    #endif

    output = (*gEnv)->NewObjectArray(gEnv, 4, clsString, NULL);
    (*gEnv)->SetObjectArrayElement(gEnv, output, 0, buf_output[0]);
    (*gEnv)->SetObjectArrayElement(gEnv, output, 1, buf_output[1]);
    (*gEnv)->SetObjectArrayElement(gEnv, output, 2, buf_output[2]);
    (*gEnv)->SetObjectArrayElement(gEnv, output, 3, buf_output[3]);

    return output;
}
```

I am controlling lifetime of AssetFileDescriptors. I don't use terminated FileDescriptors.
Do I have to re-code I/O routines in Java or not to free allocated memories?
it often causes SIGSEGV on third for-loop. but sometimes on fourth loop.

```
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        sprintf (temp, "%s%s", header[i], index[fileno[i]]);
        strBuf = getTextByIndex(&filebuf, temp); //malloc() in this function.
        if (strBuf == NULL)
            buf_output[i] = NULL;
        else

        {
            buf_output[i] = (*gEnv)->NewStringUTF(gEnv, strBuf);
            free(strBuf);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `char    indexPrefix` rather than `char *indexPrefix`? Calling `utf8len` on a single unterminated character seems strange.

Comment: @sarnold utf8len wasn't in ndk, so I have made one by myself. and my utf8len() is not for string but it's job is calculating a character's byte-length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged by putting this 1 line code right after free(strBuf); (though there is no repeating free(strBuf)...)

```
strBuf = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on Galaxy S and it worked well on Galaxy S (2.2). I have not tried it on another Nexus One in order to know if my Nexus One is faulty.

and it seems like that AssetFileDescriptor is not the source of the problem, because the problem is still ocurring while I didn't access asset files directly but accessing copied ones.